# Calculate Prometheus volume size to store metrics

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

We are using prometheus operator and we want now to store the data on disk,
There is a blog that explain it, but not sure about the numbers /size response that coming from the query

https://www.robustperception.io/how-much-disk-space-do-prometheus-blocks-use

I use in the Prometheus query UI

rate(prometheus_tsdb_compaction_chunk_size_bytes_sum[24h]) / rate(prometheus_tsdb_compaction_chunk_samples_sum[24h])

and got values

```
endpoint="web",instance="100.96.10.7:9090",job="per-prometheus",namespace="monitoring",pod="per-prometheus-1",service="per-prometheus"}
```

value **0.9017483000151686**

```
{endpoint="web",instance="100.96.7.10:9090",job="per-prometheus",namespace="monitoring",pod="per-prometheus-0",service="per-prometheus"}
```

value = **0.880271256152723**

My question is what is this numbers , is it size in GB ?

is it `0.88027125615272 + 0.9017483000151686 = 1.8 GB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is bytes per sample. Taking the number as 0.9 that means that if you were ingesting 1000 samples per second, that'd be `.9*1000*86400 = ~75MB` per day as an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. how do I know how much samples we are running per seconds ? we are using out of the box https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: if I check the head I got the following `Head chunks 798243
Head time series 485655
WAL corruptions 0
Goroutines 323
GOMAXPROCS 8`

Comment: Could you please advice regard the number of samples? This is the only  thing that I miss